# The snap installation wine program displays very small at high resolution

Tags: wine, display, display-resolution

To make the program appear uppercase at high resolution, I adjusted the settings：
setting -- display -- scale 200%

The other programs look normal, but the programs installed through Snap Wine still look very small

sudo snap install notepad-plus-plus

Notepad++looks very small